# ListView onItemClick: NullPointerException retrieving views

Tags: android

I cant click on list view to pass new activity. please advice me how to solve this problem.

here my code

```
// set UI
        setContentView(R.layout.show_permission);

        //get list from background
        show = getListView();

        //object for permission list
        permission_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

        // get uid from main activity
        Intent i = getIntent();
        uid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_UID);

        // get data from background thread
        new GetPermission().execute();



        show.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //getting item from list Item
                String project_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.report_id)).getText().toString(); <---error here
                String project_name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();

                Intent in = getIntent();
                //send report_id to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_PROJECT_ID, project_id);
                in.putExtra(TAG_PROJECT_NAME, project_name);
                in.putExtra(TAG_UID, uid);
                setResult(100, in);

                finish();
            }
        });
```

and here log cat display

```
    09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.example.androidhive.ProjectPermission$1.onItemClick(ProjectPermission.java:82)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-25 15:41:27.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1457):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks for help!

Comment: To which activity you want to return the data?

Comment: Please share the list item view layout file..

Answer (score 1):

one of

```
((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.report_id)).getText().toString();
```

is null.

- view : wouln't make sense
- findViewById(R.id.report_id)) : are you sure this view exists in the item layout ?
- getText() : the text of the report_id view can be null

Comment: launch your app in debug mode. put a breakpoint at your 82nd line, run, and when you reach the breakpoint, observe the value of each 3 elements (view, findViewById, getText). One of these has to be null for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
String project_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.report_id)).getText().toString();
```

try this :

**`mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.report_id);`**

**`String project_id = mTextView.getText().toString();`**

Comment: sorry It's work but It cant get value from textview (setVisible="gone").

Comment: Oh, so you want the text of a TextView which has `visibility = gone` ?

Comment: but it cant get value for pass to new activity

Comment: Oh, well, in that case you should create a new question. Because your current question is about ListViews and in StackOverflow it is much better to ask only question per post. Plus I believe that you are likely to get more help if your title is more specific about getting the text from the gone textView. And as far as this question post is concerned, please do upvote/accept my answer if it was of any help. Good luck ahead! Cheers! :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a textview variables say tv, then

tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.report_id);

After you've attached 'tv' to its id, try getting the text from it, using

String str = tv.getText().toString();

Display the string 'str' in a 'Toast' to find out if it does not hold a null value, if that doesn't work post your code here.

Comment: I check it from log cat. textview have value

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following approach:

```
  String project_id = ((TextView) view.getChildAt(index of project id view)).getText().toString(); 

  String project_name = ((TextView) view.getChildAt(index of project name view)).getText().toString();
```

For example if the project id text view is first view in your list item view then pass `0` as index of project ID.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all replied I found solution to fix it here

```
setContentView(R.layout.show_permission);

        ListView lv = getListView();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        uid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_UID);


        //report list
        permission_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        //load report in background
        new GetPermission().execute();

        // listView OnClicklistener
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //getting item from list Item
                String project_name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pro_name)).getText().toString();

                // pass data to edit
                Intent edit = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimeReport.class);

                //send report_id to next activity
                edit.putExtra(TAG_PROJECT_NAME, project_name);
                edit.putExtra(TAG_UID, uid);

                startActivityForResult(edit, 100);
            }
```